# string Vector push_back failing in class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a class with a method that should return a vector of strings. the getCommVector method has to push_back the elements of a string array into a string vector that can then be returned by the method. When trying to add a string element to the string vector i get:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
2Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I cannot understand why I can't push_back strings to the vector. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

code segments of interest (edited after suggestions):

```
class Command {
public:
    //Command (std::string, bool, bool);
    void setOperators(std::string,bool, bool);
    void analyseCommand();
    Command();
    std::vector<std::string> getCommVector ();
private:
    int numOperators; //number of total commands
    int opCount; //current command number
    std::string input_string;
    bool field_command, byte_command;
    std::string commVector[3];
    std::vector<std::string> finalCommVector;
    void byte_analysis();
    void field_analysis();
    void decode_command();
    void syntax_error();
    void decode_error();
};


Command::Command() : numOperators(0), opCount(0),  field_command(false),byte_command(false)
{

}
std::vector<std::string> Command::getCommVector ()
{
    std::string s ="test";
    finalCommVector.push_back("s");
    return finalCommVector;
}
```

adding SSCE:

```
class Command {
    public:
        //Command (std::string, bool, bool);
        void setOperators(std::string,bool, bool);
        void analyseCommand();
        Command();
        std::vector<std::string> getCommVector ();
    private:
        int numOperators; //number of total commands
        int opCount; //current command number
        std::string input_string;
        bool field_command, byte_command;
        std::string commVector[3];
        std::vector<std::string> finalCommVector;
        void byte_analysis();
        void field_analysis();
        void decode_command();
        void syntax_error();
        void decode_error();

};


Command::Command() : numOperators(0), opCount(0), field_command(false),byte_command(false)
{

}

void Command::syntax_error()
{
    std::cout<<"Incorrect Syntax Error: Usage: linuxcut -b num -f num \n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void Command::decode_error()
{
    std::cout<<"Decode Error: Usage: linuxcut -b num -f num \n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


void Command::analyseCommand()
{
    if (byte_command) {
        //start byte command analysys
        byte_analysis();
    }
    else if (field_command)
    {
        //start field command analysys
        field_analysis();
    }
}




void Command::setOperators(std::string input_argument, bool is_field, bool is_byte)
{
    input_string = input_argument;

    field_command = is_field;
    byte_command = is_byte;
}

std::vector<std::string> Command::getCommVector ()
{

    std::string s = "ssd";
    finalCommVector.push_back(s);
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(commVector); i++)
    {

        if (commVector[i] != "")
        {
            //debug

            std::cout<<"asdas";
        }


    }
     */
    return finalCommVector;
}


void Command::byte_analysis()
{
    int next_state = 0;
    int dashCount = 0;
    int commVectIndex = 0;




    //iterate through string and check if the argument is valid
    for (int i= 0; i<input_string.length(); i++) {



        switch (next_state) {
            case 0: //start
                //if character is a number:
                if (isdigit(input_string.at(i)))
                {
                    //first elemnt of command commVector is number
                    commVector[commVectIndex]+=input_string.at(i);

                    //DEBUG
                    std::cout<<commVector[commVectIndex];
                    next_state = 1;
                }
                //if character is a dash:
                else if (input_string[i] == '-')
                {
                    //increment dashCount
                    dashCount++;
                    //if next character in input_string is a number continue
                    if (isdigit(input_string[i+1])) {
                        commVector[commVectIndex]+=input_string.at(i);
                        commVectIndex++;
                        next_state = 1;
                    }
                    else //else error
                    {
                        syntax_error();
                    }
                }
                //if it's niether: error!
                else
                {

                    syntax_error();
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                //if next character is a number:
                if (isdigit(input_string[i]))
                {
                    commVector[commVectIndex]+=input_string.at(i);
                    next_state = 1;
                }
                //if next character is dash
                else if (input_string[i] == '-'&& dashCount <= 3)
                {
                    dashCount++;
                    //increment commandVectIndex
                    commVectIndex++;
                    next_state = 2;
                    commVector[commVectIndex]+=input_string.at(i);
                    //increment commandVectIndex to accomodate next operation
                    commVectIndex++;
                }

                //if it's niether: error!
                else
                {

                    syntax_error();
                }
                break;

            case 2://previous character was dash
                //if next character is number
                if (isdigit(input_string[i]))
                {
                    commVector[commVectIndex]+=input_string.at(i);
                    next_state = 1;
                }

                //if it's niether: error!
                else
                {

                    syntax_error();
                }
                break;

            default:
                syntax_error();
                break;
        }

    }

}



void Command::field_analysis()
{

}
/*****************FUNCTIONS DEFINITIONS***************/

void print_usage() {
    std::cout<<"Incorrect Syntax Error: Usage: linuxcut -b num -f num \n";
}



/*****************END OF FUNCTIONS DEFINITIONS***************/


/***************** MAIN ***************/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt= 0;
    std::string byte = "-1-2,2",field = "";
    std::string sub_arg_delimiter = ","; //delimiter for comma serparated arguments
    static bool complement = false;
    int diffOpt = 0; //stores the difference between optind  and argc to read filenames in command
    std::string fileName;
    //Specifying the expected options
    //The two options l and b expect numbers as argument
    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"byte",      required_argument,       0,  'b' },
        {"field", required_argument,       0,  'f' },
        {"complement",    no_argument, 0,  0 },
        {0,           0,                 0,  0   }
    };

    Command testCommand;
    testCommand.setOperators("-2-", false, true);

    std::vector<std::string> trial = testCommand.getCommVector();


    std::cout<<"filename:"<<fileName<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Selected flags:\n"<< "b: "<< byte<<"\nf: "<<field<<"\ncomplement: "<<complement<<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(commVector)` yields `3*sizeof(std::string)`, the size in bytes, not the number of elements.

Comment: Should this possibly be <br/>`finalCommVector.push_back(s);`  Without the apostrophs?

Comment: thanks, I'll address that problem now. I tried though taking that statement away and just tried to do a simple push_back to  finalComm Vector of a string and it fails (no loops or anything) and it still fails :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is the array of `std::string commVector` as a `std::vector<String>`, you can use `std::vecor::assign`:
    `finalCommVector.assign(commVector, commVector+3)`

The '3' is the length of you array.

Comment: `assign` replaces the contents, so the behaviour is different from `push_back`. (Not sure which one the OP wants, though.)

Comment: I have tried assign, but I it gets stuck in an infinite loop when I step in the assign function?

Comment: Something is rotten elsewhere in you program. Please provide a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) where you can demonstrate your problem.

Comment: where can I upload it? sorry first time I have to upload a SSCE

Comment: Should not be much more than one cpp-file. Edit your first post, add a sentence that you took the advice given in the comments (as you are invalidating them all!) and add you program.

Comment: I have added the SSCE, it's not that long at the end :)

Comment: Your code does not even compile!
`Error 2 error C2552: 'long_options' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list e:\projects\tests\stackoverflow-test\commands.cpp 203 Stackoverflow-Test`

`Error 3 error C2065: 'required_argument' : undeclared identifier e:\projects\tests\stackoverflow-test\commands.cpp 203 Stackoverflow-Test`
These two lines are repeated for each of the lines in the long_options definition. What is `option`?

Comment: After adding a suitable definition for `option`, your program runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

You're iterating way beyond the array size. `sizeof(commVector)` returns the size of the array *in bytes.*

If you have C++11 available, you can do this:

```
for (const auto &s : commVector) {
  if (s != "") {
    // as before
  }
}
```

Or at least this (if you only have partial C++11 support):

```
for (auto it = std::begin(commVector); it != std::end(commVector); ++it) {
  std::string s = *it;
  // the rest as before
}
```

Without C++11, you can at least do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(commVector) / sizeof(commVector[0]); ++i) {
  // the rest as before
}
```

Or provide your own function for obtaining the correct array size:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
size_t arraySize(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }

// Use:

for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize(commVector); ++i) {
  // the rest as before
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately that does not fix my problem with the push_back. I have now taken off the loop just for testing purposes and it still fails I reduced the method to:
    std::string s = "ssd";
    finalCommVector.push_back(s);

Comment: @realn00b Then the problem is probably somewhere else. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: the whole code is pretty long but in a single source file, where can I post it?

Comment: @realn00b Don't. If you want us to spend time helping you, be ready to invest some yourself in removing the unrelated bits first. Perhaps this will even help you find the problem yourself. That's why you should prepare an SSCCE *before* you ask on SO in the first place.

Comment: My bad, will do that now!

Comment: @realn00b No problem. Once you have a minimal reproducing case, edit your question and add it in there.

Comment: I have added it, it should be executable

Comment: @realn00b Ouch, that's quite a lot of code. Can't you reduce it further (e.g. hardcode the required options instead of parsing them etc.)?

Comment: I've hardcoded the main, should be smaller now :) thanks a lot for all the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39184/discussion-between-realn00b-and-angew)

Answer (score 2):

```
i<sizeof(commVector);
```

should be

```
i<countof(commVector);
```

if countof/_countof is defined for your compiler. If not, you can do it yourself, it is typically defined as:

```
#define countof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))
```

and I won't go into discussion about using macros in C++ :)

Of course, you could also use a constant are your array has fixed number of elements, but I guess it's just an example.

`sizeof` returns the size of the object (in this case the string array) itself, not the count of elements inside the vector.

Because of this, it is equal to number of the array elements multiplied by size of a single string instance, so you try to access non-existing items with `operator[]`.

This is also broken:

```
finalCommVector.push_back("s");
```

and probably you meant:

```
finalCommVector.push_back(s);
```

Comment: oh, yes, I confused finalCommVector. thanks, I will fix the answer